# gridview RowUpdating index

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

When adding items to a gridview, I want the user to be able to select and edit/remove the item before writing the file (from the gridview entries) to a csv format.  When I click on "edit" and update the information, I get an error.  There is no row at position 0. (or whatever row you select to edit).  Here is my code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        SetFocus(parttxtbox);
        table = new DataTable();
        MakeDataTable();
    }
    else
        table = (DataTable)ViewState["table"];

    ViewState["table"] = table;
}

protected void MakeDataTable()
{
    table.Columns.Add("Part", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(Int32));
    table.Columns.Add("Ship-To", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Requested Date", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Shipping Method", typeof(string));

    //Persist the table in the Session object.
    Session["table"] = table;

    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData();
}

protected void addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    part = parttxtbox.Text.ToUpper();
    shipto = shiptotxtbox.Text;
    reqdate = reqdatecal.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
    shipmthd = shipddl.SelectedItem.ToString();
    CreateTable();
 }

public void CreateTable()
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    row["Part"] = part;
    row["Quantity"] = qty;
    row["Ship-To"] = shipto;
    row["Requested Date"] = reqdate;
    row["Shipping Method"] = shipmthd;
    table.Rows.Add(row);

    griditems.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
    griditems.DataBind();
}

private void BindData()
{
    griditems.DataSource = table;
    griditems.DataBind();
}

protected void griditems_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    //Retrieve the table from the session object.
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["table"];

    //Update the values.           
    GridViewRow row = griditems.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Part"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
    dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Quantity"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
    dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Ship-To"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text;
    dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Requested Date"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text;
    dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Shipping Method"] = ((DropDownList)(row.Cells[5].Controls[0])).SelectedItem.ToString();


    //Reset the edit index.
    griditems.EditIndex = -1;
    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData();

    ////Somewhat works, doesn't update the part field with the text entered
    //TextBox partedit = (TextBox)griditems.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Part");
    //DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    //row["Part"] = partedit;
    //row["Quantity"] = qty;
    //row["Ship-To"] = shipto;
    //row["Requested Date"] = reqdate;
    //row["Shipping Method"] = shipmthd;
    //table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

The commented out part that says "Somewhat works" will write blanks in the field updated when you click update.

Comment: shouldn't there be an SQL statement for update?

Comment: @JimS.:   sample for gridview add/update functionalty http://bit.ly/NIxCPO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time you are adding data table in Session `there is no row in it`, thats why you get error `"There is no row at position 0."`

You are assigning table from viewstate to table it would be session.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        SetFocus(parttxtbox);
        table = new DataTable();
        MakeDataTable();
    }
    else
    if(Session["table"] != null)
        table = (DataTable)ViewState["table"];
}

protected void MakeDataTable()
{
    table.Columns.Add("Part", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(Int32));
    table.Columns.Add("Ship-To", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Requested Date", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Shipping Method", typeof(string));

    //Persist the table in the Session object.
    Session["table"] = table; //This adds table without any record in it. 

    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData();
}
```

Add data table to session after you add records in datatable.

```
protected void addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    part = parttxtbox.Text.ToUpper();
    shipto = shiptotxtbox.Text;
    reqdate = reqdatecal.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
    shipmthd = shipddl.SelectedItem.ToString();
    CreateTable();
    Session["table"] = table;
 }
```

Update the Session["table"] in griditems_RowUpdating after updating.

```
protected void griditems_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    //Retrieve the table from the session object.
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["table"];

    //Update the values.           
    GridViewRow row = griditems.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Part"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
    dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Quantity"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
    dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Ship-To"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text;
    dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Requested Date"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text;
    dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Shipping Method"] = ((DropDownList)(row.Cells[5].Controls[0])).SelectedItem.ToString();


    //Reset the edit index.
    griditems.EditIndex = -1;
    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData();

    Session["table"] = dt; 
}
```

Note: The way you are trying to get the updating recording is not appropriate you should read more about how to access data on row updating.

Comment: Well, i do not have the index problem now, but the gridview doesn't show the updated changes, only the old values from initially entered.

Comment: Try assign table back to session in griditems_RowUpdating, updated my answer

Comment: Tried to reassign the table back to session - still not updating changes.

Comment: You are assigning table from viewstate to table it would be session, I updated my answer

Comment: I think we are almost near to solve it, you may debug the code to find out what is missing, here you can find out how to debug http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316726

Comment: Finally Found it...
[READ THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146488/gridview-edit-when-bound-toa-datatable)